# jQuery: html shows nothing with no error, maybe head error?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Sorry for poor English, it is my second language.

I am trying to fix a code from codepen that uses jQuery. It is a code for carousel that slides auto. However, when I try to move these code to my own file, my html does not show up carousel. There is no error on console log.
Here is my HTML header

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.1.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is the javascript file(main.js) that I am trying to use

```
var sliderTeam = (function(document, $) {
  
    'use strict';
    
    var $sliderTeams = $('.slider--teams'),
        $list = $('#list'),
        $listItems = $('#list li'),
        $nItems = $listItems.length,
        $nView = 3,
        autoSlider,
        $current = 0,
        $isAuto = true,
        $acAuto = 2500,
        
        _init = function() {
          _initWidth();
          _eventInit();
        },
        
        _initWidth = function() {
          $list.css({
            'margin-left': ~~(100 / $nView) + '%',
            'width': ~~(100 * ($nItems / $nView)) + '%'
          });
          $listItems.css('width', 100 / $nItems + '%');
          $sliderTeams.velocity({ opacity: 1 }, { display: "block" }, { delay:1000 });
        },
        
        _eventInit = function() {
          
          window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
            return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
                function(callback, element){
                  window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                };
          })();
  
          window.requestInterval = function(fn, delay) {
              if( !window.requestAnimationFrame       && 
                  !window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame && 
                  !window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    && 
                  !window.oRequestAnimationFrame      && 
                  !window.msRequestAnimationFrame)
                      return window.setInterval(fn, delay);
              var start = new Date().getTime(),
              handle = new Object();
  
              function loop() {
                  var current = new Date().getTime(),
                  delta = current - start;
                  if(delta >= delay) {
                      fn.call();
                      start = new Date().getTime();
                  }
                  handle.value = requestAnimFrame(loop);
              };
              handle.value = requestAnimFrame(loop);
              return handle;
          }
  
          window.clearRequestInterval = function(handle) {
              window.cancelAnimationFrame ? window.cancelAnimationFrame(handle.value) :
              window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame ? window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame(handle.value)   :
              window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame ? window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame(handle.value) :
              window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame ? window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame(handle.value) :
              window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame ? msCancelRequestAnimationFrame(handle.value) :
              clearInterval(handle);
          };
          
          $.each($listItems, function(i) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.on('touchstart click', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              _stopMove(i);
              _moveIt($this, i);
            });
          });
          
          autoSlider = requestInterval(_autoMove, $acAuto);
        },
        
        _moveIt = function(obj, x) {
          
          var n = x;
          
          obj.find('figure').addClass('active');        
          $listItems.not(obj).find('figure').removeClass('active');
          
          $list.velocity({
            translateX: ~~((-(100 / $nItems)) * n) + '%',
            translateZ: 0
          }, {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: [400, 26],
            queue: false
          });
          
        },
        
        _autoMove = function(currentSlide) {
          if ($isAuto) { 
            $current = ~~(($current + 1) % $nItems);
          } else {
            $current = currentSlide;
          }
          console.log($current);
          _moveIt($listItems.eq($current), $current);
        },
        
        _stopMove = function(x) {
          clearRequestInterval(autoSlider);
          $isAuto = false;
          _autoMove(x);
        };
    
    return {
      init: _init
    };
  
  })(document, jQuery);
  
  $(window).load(function(){
    'use strict';
    sliderTeam.init();
  });
```

This is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/fixcl/pen/KwpKvb

Did I add the wrong version of js file? Or did I miss something else?

Edited:
main.js is connected to html file. I can check with the code from main.js

```
console.log($current);
```

Edited2: This is my body of html file

```
<body>
<div class="slider--teams">
    <div class="slider--teams__team">
      <ul id="list" class="cf">
        <li>
          <figure class="active">
            <figcaption>
              <img src="https://odium.kr/assets/css/images/symbol-cernium.png">
              <h2>Billie</h2>
              <p>Head of Team</p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </li>

        <li>
          <figure>
            <figcaption>
              <img src="https://odium.kr/assets/css/images/symbol-arcus.png">
              <h2>Roger</h2>
              <p>Art Director</p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </li>

        <li>
          <figure>
            <figcaption>
                          <img src="https://odium.kr/assets/css/images/symbol-odium.png">
              <h2>Wendy</h2>
              <p>Designer</p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </li>  
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: try putting `console.log('this works')` js file. If the word show in console the js is just fine, if isn't maybe you are not calling the js file

Comment: @Japs If you see the main.js, it has code ```console.log($current);```  it keep shows 0 on console which means main.js is in the html

Comment: what's content inside your html body?

Comment: Also is css correctly linked?

Comment: @huanfeng I just added to the question, please check it

Comment: @Harshal Yes it is

Comment: dont use regular `CSS`. This [link](https://codepen.io/fixcl/pen/KwpKvb) is using [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put the main.js before body close tag, since you need to start execute main.js after DOM element is ready.
please check the plnkr for detail:
https://plnkr.co/edit/CuN7q7j6lrQE57DH?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

```
<body>
...
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```